# RESTORE cannot process database 'MyDataBaseName' because it is in use by this session

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to restore the database backup (.BAK) file in my vb.net windows application. but i am getting this error( RESTORE cannot process database 'MyDataBaseName' because it is in use by this session. It is recommended that the master database be used when performing this operation.  RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.) here is the code for the restoration process:

```
Private Sub DbRestoreButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DbRestoreButton.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim SourcePath As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Dim DatabaseName As String = "MyDatabaseName"

        RestoreDatabase(DatabaseName, SourcePath)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub RestoreDatabase(ByVal DatabaseName As String, ByVal SourcePath As String)

    Try
        Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbx").ConnectionString
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)

            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("RESTORE DATABASE @DatabaseName FROM DISK = @SourcePath WITH REPLACE", conn)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatabaseName", DatabaseName)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SourcePath", SourcePath)

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show("Database Restored Succesfully", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As ApplicationException
        MsgBox("ERROR" & ex.Message, "ERROR")
    End Try

End Sub
```

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: What's your connection string? Because the error seems to indicate that you connect to the database you're trying to restore

Comment: "dbx" is the connections string and yes its for the current database. Is this the reason? how to resolve this?